# How to change the url for jenkins?

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I created an EC2 instance and deployed a Django application using Gunicorn and Nginx. In order to build pipelines for the application I installed jenkins in the same host. Now I wanted to access jenkins using the dns (`jenkins.mydnsname.com` or `www.mydnsname.com/jenkins`). Currently, the jenkins is accessible using the public ip of my instance at `http://mypublicip:8080/`. How can I change the url

I have tried to add the following config in my nginx but it didn't work

```
location /jenkins {
        sendfile off;
        proxy_pass         http://myip:8080/;
        proxy_redirect     default;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        #this is the maximum upload size
        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;
        proxy_buffering            off;
        proxy_request_buffering    off; # Required for HTTP CLI commands
        proxy_set_header Connection ""; # Clear for keepalive
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have starting Jenkins through Tomcat, before starting the server, export the following environment variable which will start Jenkins with the added context. If not you can add the following to your Jenkisns startup command. (`java -jar jenkins............. --prefix=/jenkins`)

```
export JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```

Then your Nginx configs should work.